# launch cassandra-cli error

Tags: ant, build, cassandra

I get the following errors when I try to run cassandra-cli.

```
manuzhang@manuzhang-U24E:~/git/cassandra-trunk$ bin/cassandra-cli -h localhost -p 9160
Column Family assumptions read from /home/manuzhang/.cassandra-cli/assumptions.json
Connected to: "Test Cluster" on localhost/9160
Welcome to Cassandra CLI version Unknown

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.AssertionError
    at org.apache.cassandra.cli.CliClient.loadHelp(CliClient.java:178)
    at org.apache.cassandra.cli.CliClient.getHelp(CliClient.java:171)
    at org.apache.cassandra.cli.CliClient.printBanner(CliClient.java:197)
    at org.apache.cassandra.cli.CliMain.main(CliMain.java:312)
```

That line is:

```
final InputStream is = CliClient.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("org/apache/cassandra/cli/CliHelp.yaml");
assert is != null;
```

The file is actually located in `$CASSANDRA_HOME/src/resources/org/apache/cassandra/cli`.

I have run it successfully for several times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

well, solved by `ant build` in terminal.

I think it's because I'm building from source and from time to time I modify some codes.

but just adding several lines of comments cannot reproduce the problem.